# sort results of array count values into a new array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, count, duplicates

I want to sort the results to a new array but without the $key
so the most UNunique number will be first (or the most duplicated number will be first).

```
<?php

$a = array (1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5);

foreach (array_count_values($a) as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.' - '.$value.'<br>'; 
}

//I am expecting to get the most duplicated number FIRST (without the $key)
//so in that case :
// $newarray = array(4,3,2,1,5); 
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _without the $key_? Are 4,3,2,1,5 the keys of the new array?

Comment: iow... The results of the new array would be :


$newarray = array(4,3,2,1,5);

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = array (1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5);

$totals = array_count_values($a);

arsort( $totals );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($totals);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [4] => 5
    [3] => 4
    [2] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [5] => 1
)
```

Comment: This is WORKING but I was wondering if there is a shorter method :)

Comment: Is it better like this? Maybe sorting can be done in same line.. not sure.

Comment: @user3301364, My **+1** This is the shortest method as it can get !

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
<?php
$a = array (1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$n=array_count_values($a);
arsort($n);
print_r(array_keys($n));
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/102649)</kbd>

**OUTPUT**:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 9
    [5] => 8
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 7
)
```

Comment: // replace to that line
// $a = array (1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9);
// I'm not getting the values of 7,8,9

Comment: @user3301364 You can try your input in the Demo link that Nambi has provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array_keys(array_count_values($a));
```

Comment: $a = array (1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5);

foreach (array_keys(array_count_values($a)) as $key => $value) {
        echo $value.'<br>'; 
}

// this is not what I'm expecting to get 0 1 2 3 4

Comment: You wanted new array not printing it out ;-D